# Google OAuth2 with offline, installed app, Do I need to store my refresh token separately from the access token?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api-php-client

I believe that I've got my code working, but I'm just trying to understand if I'm doing something wrong, because the documentation all seems to make this sound like it should be an automatic process but I'm having to do it manually. Please make sure to read through to the end to understand my real question (I've had a lot of people jump to conclusions on my recent questions and answer the wrong thing.)

I've got a web app where I need some of my scripts to be able to perform some authenticated tasks using Google APIs (v2.0 of the php client). I created an access token using a script on the command line [from Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/quickstart/php).

In that code example:

1. the access token is written to a file
2. the access token is read back in when the script is run again
3. if the access token expires, it's refreshed
4. the access token file is overwritten with the newly refreshed access token

However, when I put this into practice, the system fails after the first token expires, because the newly refreshed access token that comes back doesn't have a `refresh_token` in it.

The initial token I receive looks like this:

```
{
  "access_token": "rituwyeorityweourtyoiuwrtoiuwyeorityiwuerytoiweurt",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 3600,
  "refresh_token": "1\/askdhfkahsdfkasjdhfklashdkfhasdflkjf-a",
  "created": 1455921953
}
```

However, all subsequent access tokens received while refreshing the access token come back without the `refresh_token` key/value in it, like this:

```
{
  "access_token": "askjdfhlkajsdhflkjahsldkfjhkalsjdhkflahdlfjah",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 3600,
  "created": 1455915147
}
```

I'm creating my token with `offline` permission [as stated in the Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline):

```
$client->setAccessType('offline');
```

It says (emphasis mine):

> After a user grants offline access to the requested scopes, you can
>   continue to use the API client to access Google APIs on the user's
>   behalf when the user is offline. ***The client object will refresh the
>   access token as needed.***

When I create the client and give it the access token from my file, I check if the access token is expired and, if so, try to refresh it:

```
if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->refreshToken();
    $newtokenjson = json_encode($client->getAccessToken());
    file_put_contents($credentialsPath, $newtokenjson);
}
```

However, the new access token is the one without the `refresh_token` I showed above, and if the access token doesn't have the `refresh_token` key in it, then Google won't actually renew my access and let me continue making requests.

I believe that I've "solved" it by storing the initial `refresh_token` in a separate file in addition to the access token and when I'm trying to refresh my current access token I force the old `refresh_token` into it, but that's not explained ANYWHERE that I can find in the documentation...

```
if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $refreshtoken = file_get_contents(REFRESH_TOKEN_PATH);
    $client->refreshToken($refreshtoken);
    $newtokenjson = json_encode($client->getAccessToken());
    file_put_contents($credentialsPath, $newtokenjson);
}
```

and so I feel like I'm hacking something that shouldn't be hacked in this fashion and that things will break later on.

In short, I'm reusing the initial `refresh_token` on every single refresh request forever.

Is this how I'm ***supposed*** to do this and, if so, why on earth is this never mentioned in the documentation or in the example code given by Google?

If it is mentioned somewhere and I missed it, please, please let me know where it is so that I can stop worrying that I've done something bad with my code that will come back to bite me in production when we push this product live.

Comment: Hi Kenny, it does state that you should store the refreshtoken. That only comes in the first request and you should use it in all future requests.
I am having the issue that the second request is not getting a new access token and I save the refreshtoken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm new to this myself and don't completely have my head around it, but maybe this will help.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/guides/authorization/server-side-web-apps#OAuth2_Refreshing_a_Token

So it seems one should store the refresh token.

Additionally, I found that if I set approval_prompt = 'force' with the following line of code: $client->setapprovalPrompt('force'); I can always get a refresh token, but sounds like that is a bad idea based on the documentation :

"Note that there are limits on the number of refresh tokens that will be issued; one limit per client/user combination, and another per user across all clients. You should save refresh tokens in long-term storage and continue to use them as long as they remain valid. If your application requests too many refresh tokens, it may run into these limits, in which case older refresh tokens will stop working."

Comment: Thank you!! I have never been able to find that line: `You should save refresh tokens in long-term storage and continue to use them as long as they remain valid.`